# Can you access bluetooth or Audio devices over XRDP

Tags: audio, remote, bluetooth, access-control, xrdp

I have setup XRDP on a ubuntu computer that I wanted to access remotely. There are Bluetooth and audio devices attached to that remote device that I would like to access. Using XRDP, it shows that there is no Bluetooth dongle and under Audio(Sounds) there are no microphones and the only output audio is a "Dummy Output".

Is there a way to gain access to these hardware devices over XRDP? I have also tried Chrome Remote Desktop and I get the same thing.

Local:
Windows 10 Pro

Remote:
Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant to you, but I will still post what I did. To get access to the local audio devices (show plugged in devices instead of Dummy Output) of your remote machine you have to add your user to the audio group, to get access to bluetooth I had to add my user to the lp, plugdev, and bluetooth groups. Don't ask me why you need to be part of the printer group lp in order to get access to bluetooth, but that is how it is. After adding your user to all groups restart your remote computer and it should work. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).